# An equivalent of javax.nio.Buffer.flip() in c#

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I am porting some of the java code and need to be able to flip (`javax.nio.Buffer.flip()`).

I am using byte[] to store data, and I want to **flip** these byte array, much like Buffer does it, as I believe underneath Buffer class uses byte[] as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ByteBuffer` may use a `byte[]` (create from, say, `ByteBuffer.wrap`) or non-Java heap memory (created with `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`). You can get the underlying `byte[]` with `ByteBuffer.array`. But calling `flip` and similar methods on buffers does not chnage the actual data. Instead offsets associated with the data are changed. So the equivalent with `byte` would be to change the offsets that your code is associating with it.

Comment: Thanks, how does flip changes the offset?

Comment: As documented... "The limit is set to the current position and then the position is set to zero."

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct equivalent of the `java.nio` package in .NET. Asynchronous IO is usually handled with `Stream.BeginRead`/`EndRead`, but it's not really the same model. Could you tell us what you're trying to do?

EDIT: You've now provided the low-level details of what you're trying to do, but as there's no real equivalent for the `nio` classes in .NET, you'll *either* have to write them yourself (not impossible, but a pain) or use a different higher level type. You might be able to use `MemoryStream` for example - write into it, then seek back to the start. That's a *bit* like flipping a byte buffer. However, we can't tell whether or not that's appropriate without more information as to the higher-level goal. There may be a much better way of doing it.