# What is the equivalent of "ByteBuffer.flip" & "ByteBuffer.slice" in .NET?

Tags: c#, memorystream, slice, flip, bytebuffer

I need to port code from Java to C#. In the Java code, the methods "ByteBuffer.flip()" and "ByteBuffer.slice" is used, and I don't know how to translate this.

I've read this question ([An equivalent of javax.nio.Buffer.flip() in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607587/an-equivalent-of-javax-nio-buffer-flip-in-c)), but although an answer is given, I cannot figure how to apply it. According to Tom Hawtin, I should "Set the limit to the current position and then set the position to zero" in the underlying array. I am unsure as of how to change these values. (If you could explain the underlying logic, it would help me a lot :)

As for the ByteBuffer.slice, I have no clue on how to translate it.

EDIT: If it can be clearer with the actual code, I'll post it:

Java:

```
ByteBuffer buff;
buff.putShort((short) 0);
buff.put(customArray);
buff.flip();
buff.putShort((short) 0);
ByteBuffer b = buff.slice();

short size = (short) (customFunction(b) + 2);
buff.putShort(0, size);
buff.position(0).limit(size);
```

So far, my translation in C#.NET:

```
BinaryWriter b = new BinaryWriter(); //ByteBuffer buff;
b.Write((short)0); // buff.putShort((short) 0);
b.Write(paramStream.ToArray()); // buff.put(customArray);
b.BaseStream.SetLength(b.BaseStream.Position); // buff.flip; (not sure)
b.BaseStream.Position = 0; // buff.flip; too (not sure)
b.Write((short)0); // buff.putShort((short) 0)
??? // ByteBuffer b = buff.slice();

// Not done but I can do it, short size = (short) (customFunction(b) + 2);
??? // How do I write at a particular position?
??? // buff.position(0).limit(size); I don't know how to do this
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Changed `b.BaseStream.SetLength(b.BaseStream.Length);` to `b.BaseStream.SetLength(b.BaseStream.Position);`, based on the Java docs.

Comment: Quick FYI: These equivalents would be in .NET, not in C#.

Comment: What type of structure are you using for the ByteBuffer? List<byte>, byte[], etc?

Comment: I am using a byte[] structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(See See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice%28%29 and http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip%28%29 for java's calls)

Flip is a quick way to reset the buffer.  So for example 
(pseudocode)

```
void flip()
{
   Length = currentPos;
   currentPos = 0;
}
```

Allows you to quickly setup the buffer you presumably just wrote to for reading from the beginning.

**Update:**
Splice is a bit trickier due to the requirement that "Changes to this buffer's content will be visible in the new buffer, and vice versa; the two buffers' position, limit, and mark values will be independent".  There unfortunately is no concept of a shared portion of buffer (that i know of - theres always using arrays, detailed below) without making your own class.  The closest thing you could do is this:

Old Code:

```
ByteBuffer b = buff.slice();
```

New Code (assuming a List)

```
List<Byte> b= buff;
int bStart = buffPos; // buffPos is your way of tracking your mark
```

the downside to the code above is that there is no way for c# to hold the new starting point of the new buffer and still share it.  You'll have to manually use the new starting point whenever you do anything, from for loops (for i=bStart;...) to indexing (newList[i + bStart]...)

Your other option is to do use Byte[] arrays instead, and do something like this:

```
Byte[] b = &buff[buffPos];
```

... however that requires unsafe operations to be enabled, and I cannot vouch for its saftey, due to the garbage collector and my avoidance of the "unsafe" features.

Outside of that, theres always making your own ByteBuffer class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please read the post again, including the code examples? I think I did a correct job on the the "flip()" equivalent, correct me if I'm wrong. I'll try to implement your slice() method now. I'll post it and hope it's good. :)

Comment: I have modified my flip method to fit yours. I think it is more appropriate now. I'm still waiting for your slice method. Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but if I understand the java bits correctly, this would give you an idea on how to implement.

```
public class ByteBuffer {

    private int _Position;
    private int _Capacity;
    private byte[] _Buffer;

    private int _Start;


    private ByteBuffer(int capacity, int position, int start, byte[] buffer) {
        _Capacity = capacity;
        _Position = position;
        _Start = start;
        _Buffer = buffer;
    }

    public ByteBuffer(int capacity) : this(capacity, 0 , 0, new byte[capacity]) {
    }


    public void Write(byte item) {

        if (_Position >= _Capacity) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        _Buffer[_Start + _Position++] = item;
    }

    public byte Read() {

        if (_Position >= _Capacity) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        return _Buffer[_Start + _Position++];
    }

    public void Flip() {

        _Capacity = _Position;
        _Position = _Start;
    }

    public ByteBuffer Slice() {
        return new ByteBuffer(_Capacity-_Position, 0, _Position, _Buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I might try creating my own ByteBuffer class, but it really is hard to do.